# No muestra las fuentes font-awesome en mi APP con REACT

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

La verdad soy nuevo en react y estoy practicando, quiero mostrar en una app las fuentes de font-awesome, pero no muestra nada en la parte de que debe mostrar y la app carga sin problema.

la ruta donde instale las fuentes es:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

Mi app esta en:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\formula
```

tengo las siguientes lineas en mi archivo App.js

```
import '../formula/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import '../formaula/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

intente tambien con:

```
import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

y la misma situación, si alguien me da una luz de que estoy haciendo mal.

Si necesitan algún dato adicional, gracias por su guia.

Saulods

Comment: Cuando se trata de react o algo con nodemodules solo se instala el paquete de fontawesome y listo , la misma pagina tiene una guia para react js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si creaste tu App de React con "create-react-app", una alternativa sería importar el CDN de Font Awesome directamente en el HTML de tu proyecto.

Vas a "./carpetadetuproyecto/public/index.html" y dentro del `<Head>` de ese archivo pegas el CDN

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

De esa forma se puede usar Font Awesome en toda la App de React.

Eso se explica en la documentación de Font Awesome: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/customizing-wordpress/snippets/setup-cdn-webfont#load-all-styles

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, la idea es usar las fuentes, pero, incluyendo el import en .js del programa